# For loop including if else statements only return the last iteration. What do? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I've started javascript just today and done my research about this matter around the web. But I couldn't get the hang of the usage of closures, especially for this code I've written:

```
function writeit()
{
    var tbox = document.getElementById('a_tbox').value;
    var letters = tbox.split("");
    for(var i=0;i<letters.length;i++)
    {
        if(letters[i]==="a")
        {
            document.a_form.b_tbox.value = i+1 + ". character is a";
        }
        else if(letters[i]==="b")
        {
            document.a_form.b_tbox.value = i+1 + ". character is b";
        }
        else
        {
            document.a_form.b_tbox.value = i+1 + ". character is not a nor b";
        }
    }
}
```

As you see here, I'd like to get a string from a text box, split it to an array and change the values inside it by using a for loop. What I expect from my code is, if the text box contained "abc" as a user contribution, the output would be "1. value is a 2. value is b 3. value is not a nor b". But it only gives "3. value is not a nor b" as an output. What can be done to prevent this problem?

Comment: Code not very readable without proper indentation.

Comment: If you started with js just today, leave closure to the end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each iteration of your loop is overriding the last result since you are replacing the value of the textbox rather than adding on for each iteration. Use += to avoid this, like so:

```
document.a_form.b_tbox.value += i+1 + ". character is not a nor b";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very trivial indeed.